# How to build a ES6 express app with webpack 2 and babel?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

Given the following **Webpack 2** configuration, I want to write a express app using ES6. My `.babelrc` has only the `es2015` preset:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',

  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'server.js'),

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'server.bundle.js',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Running webpack and starting the server work fine, but when accessing the URL through the browser I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (/Users/Me/project/dist/server.bundle.js:18208:74)
```

I don't know whether it's due to the `.` in a `require('./some/other/file')` call (not all files are ES6, so these one use `require()` instead of `import`);  or maybe some configuration I'm missing.

And also, given that stack trace I can't really map it to the original source file.

Thanks in advance

**Update 1**

I just realize I'm trying to use webpack to transpile ES6 code because I'm trying to replicate another build task (the one in [mern.io](http://mern.io)), but I could do the same just with babel. Maybe there's no reason for using webpack on the serverside.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and add in webpack.config.js ExternalsPlugin:

```
plugins: [
    new ExternalsPlugin({
        type: 'commonjs',
        include: path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/'),
    }),
],
```

It helped me, I hope you too, because I spent a lot of time for solutions this problem)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is that you are using **target: "node"** on webpack config. So that means it's creating your package for nodejs environment. Can you test after changing it to **target: "web"** for client transpile?

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

Comment: I want to use it for node, not for browser. I'm trying to make an express app writing ES6+.